# amazon s3 and google search

Tags: amazon-s3, seo, google-custom-search

We have a requirement, where we will upload files to Amazon S3 buckets with metadata like File Description, Title, Author, Created Date, etc.

After that we will create a public static website from the Amazon S3 bucket. 
So, Google can index the Amazon S3 files by file links.

I have below question regarding this,

**When we add custom metatags for Amazon S3 files it shows the custom attributes (for e.g. x-amz-meta-tag1, x-amz-meta-tag2, etc.) in Response Header of file. So, are these custom metatags of files indexed by Google search engine? Means, can I search my public Amazon s3 file on google by it's metadata like "Author", "Title", etc?**

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Not unless you actively publish the tag content on the containing site.

Comment: Niels, thanks for you quick response.

So, After publishing the file on Amazon S3 publically. 
Do we need to upload/publish a HTML/web page file on our website  with "Tag Content" (Author Name, Title, File Description, etc.) in metatags?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not explicitly visible to users, you won't be able to search it with Google.

So yes, you will be able to search according to titles, because titles are visible. And no, you won't be able to see your custom meta tags, because they are not displayed to users.